# Tensorflow TFrecord file of unequal size

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I currently split my data into several TFrecord files and then read the data by shuffling & interleaving them. My code is below:

```
path_to_files = glob('train_*.tfrecord')
n_files = len(path_to_files)
tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path).shuffle(n_files)
tf_dataset = tf_dataset.interleave(lambda filename: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename, num_parallel_reads=4).map(parseFunc), cycle_length=n_files)
tf_dataset = tf_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=n_files*3)  
tf_dataset = tf_dataset.batch(batchsize)
tf_dataset = tf_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=batchsize)
```

I have 2 questions:

1) Is my cod eindeed doing what I intend it to do. Namely, does it randomly sample samples from each of the TFrecord files equally

2) What happens if the TFrecord files contain very different amount of samples (e.g. 1 will have 50 samples and another 500). Does this affect the randomness at all?

Thanks!

Comment: How many file do you have in `path_to_files` ? Have you tried your code?

Comment: @Sharky I have 6 files. I have run the code and it works and produces random batches, but since the files are very large I have not thoroughly tested it. I was hoping someone here would know offhand

Comment: Try it without parse func. It will output just filenames, and will eventually return out of range error, because there's no repeat in your code

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Not exactly. First of all, this line don't needs explicit shuffle, `list_files` already has this parameter. It's can be controlled by seed value.

```
tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path, shuffle=True, seed=1).
```

Without repeat function, you'll get end of sequence error when iterator exhausts all your files. So it should be like this. With `None` passed as a value it will iterate indefinitely, or you can set exact number of epochs.

```
tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path, shuffle=True, seed).repeat()
```

Q2: It's ok if the sizes of files is different. The only outcome is that contents of large file will have higher chance of being chosen by iterator. But it won't affect randomness. This line will do it's job, shuffling interleaved dataset. The only thing to remember, is that shuffle buffer controls amount of data, loaded into memory. It's generally recommended to set it to number of examples in dataset (number of all examples in all files), but in some cases it may become a substantial overhead and even cause OOM.

```
tf_dataset = tf_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=n_files*3)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ran a simulation to test this as follows: I saved 3 files with:
    file 1: ~1000 samples of the number 1
    file 2: ~2000 samples of the number 2
    file 3: ~3000 samples of the number 3

Then I loaded the iterator with the above code and sampled batches until the iterator ran out. Below are my results.

[image]

As can be seen in the figure, TF does NOT weigh the TFrecord files by their size when it randomly samples from them. Rather, it randomly samples from each of the unequal sized files with equal probability until one of them runs out of samples. Then it continues from each of the remaining files with equal probability.

Take home: to have truly random sampling, make sure that your TFrecord files are either equally sized or the labels are homogenously distributed between them

Comment: This is just because you don't use shuffle in `list_files`. Just try my code with one file with only one example and second file with 10 examples. You'll see, that it's exactly as I described

Comment: @Sharky i tried using your code (`tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path, shuffle=True, seed=1)`) and got the exact same result

Comment: It's strange indeed, cause your code gave me out of range error